# django using memcached cache backend — am I doing it right?

Tags: django, memcached

I am changing my backend cache strategy from filesystem to Memcached! My question is am I doing all steps right?

1. Installed memcached: `apt-get install memcached`
2. Installed python-memcached: `pip install python-memcached`
3. Changed my `CACHES` variable in the settings to this:

   ```
   CACHES = {
       'default': {
           'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
           'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
       }
   }
   ```

It is just those three steps?! Or am I missing something?

Also, do I need to start the memcached server, or will Django start it automatically?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try those steps? Are you running into any problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django does not manage start itself memcached or other services, you have to run memcached yourself.

I always try to connect to memcached myself to see if it's up and running (and accepting connections as well) using:

telnet 127.0.0.1 11211